# How implement TF-IDF scoring with additional weighting for certain terms

Tags: python, search, information-retrieval, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I currently have a tf-idf system for scoring and I'm using cosine similarity for searching. I want to add additional weighting that takes into account whether or not a given term is in the title of a document. I'm unsure of how to combine the title data with the tf-idf scores, however. Does anyone know of a good approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple paths: you could upgrade your similarity to a BM25F (fielded model) or you could replicate your TF-IDF system for title and body data. Then, instead of having one score per document, you have a TitleScore and a BodyScore that you need to combine.

You could then decide on importances heuristically, e.g., title matches are 70% and body are 30%:

```py
score = 0.7 * titleTFIDF(q, doc) + 0.3 * bodyTFIDF(q, doc)
```

Or you could try to learn weights from the data.

Comment: Do you have a link for the BM25F that the user can follow? THis will help